# Pandas dataframe multiple and sum row wise

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df of the following format

```
Market   ID     Col1      Col2     Col3   Price   Sum_Price

USA      100     0.49      0.5      0.5    100     149
EU       200     0.25      0.25     0.75   100     125
```

Essentially `Sum_Price` is equal to `(Col1*Price+Col2*Price+Col*Price)`
I have tried `df.iloc[:,2:4]*df.iloc[:,5]` but it padded a few extra columns, which I am not sure of the behaviour...
Thanks

Comment: `df.filter(regex='^Col').sum(1).mul(df['Price'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
df["total"] = df[["col1", "col2", "col3"]].sum() * df["price"]
```